# insert data from S3 to simpleDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

i have a data set, approximately 3 to 4 GB, stored in Amazon S3, is there a efficient way that i can save this data set to Amazon simpleDB? I'm new to amazon, so it is better if there's a hands on example, thanks!

Comment: You can store the dataset in a single object in Amazon S3 so dataset should be object on amazon s3. Amazon SimpleDB store any thing as a string. You need to write your own code that can read data from data-set and upload to Amazon SimpleDB or there are many third part tool available that can import data from CSV or mysql database to Amazon SimpleDB. For that you need to export your data-set in CSV or my-sql first and than you can use tool like SDBExplorer to upload data from CSV or mysql- http://www.sdbexplorer.com/

Comment: so i have to retrieve data from S3 and then store them to simpleDB? but the data set is very large, won't this process take to much time?

Comment: Yes. You have to retrieve data from S3 and then store them to simpleDB. You can use multipart download for downloading large s3 objects from Amazon S3 and to upload fast to Amazon SimpleDB you can use BatchPutAttribute.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/faqs/ http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

Comment: also keep in mind that SimpleDB is limited to 1KB / attribute

Comment: Can you explain your reason for wanting this data in SimpleDB?

Comment: Consider using Athena instead (it didn't exist in 2013)